# SignalR on WinForms - Can't connect to any address aside from 127.0.0.1

Tags: c#, signalr

I've looked up several articles/sources but none of them helped me out.

I have this bizarre issue where i can only connect to my SignalR Server (Self-Hosted, same computer) if the Server itself is configured to run on `http://127.0.0.1:8765` and the Client is pointed to that same address. However, if i change the Server to run on any IP such as `http://*:8765` and the Client is pointed it to my IP or computername, say: `http://192.168.0.1:8765` or `http://MyLocalPC:8765`, the client throws an Exception after `await _hubConnection.Start()` with message: `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 192.168.0.1:8765`.

i have tried below steps to experiment a little but none of them actually helped:

- changed the port from :8765 to any port i can think of (that is obviously not occupied), didn't work.
- changed from one Network to another, didn't help.
- disabled firewall on both Server and Client computer, nope.
- tried to run the Client on another computer, same error message.

to show a snippet of the code, see below:

Server (_signalR is an IDisposable object & _serverURI is where `http://____:__` is specified):

[image]
[image]

Client (_hubConnection & _hostAddress is self-explanatory):
[image]

i am using `C# 7.0` with `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client 2.4.1.0` and `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 2.4.1.0`

Comment: When you launch the SignalR server, run `netstat -aon` at command prompt and see what's the output.

Comment: @LexLi is there any particular entry i should be looking for after running that command? i wasn't able to find the port  that my SignalR Server is supposed to run if i use `http://*:8765` but appears if i use `http://127.0.0.1:8765`

Comment: That actually explains the symptoms further. When your app tried to bind to `http://*:8765`, it failed (so nothing is shown in `netstat` output then). Dig SignalR documentation to see if anything related can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just realized that its because **Visual Studio wasn't running with Administrator rights**.  SignalR required administrative rights to able to run its Server on IPs other than `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. I wasn't able to fully realize it since i switch laptops about 3 weeks now and forgot setting up running Visual Studio in Administrator Mode.

The reason i was also not able to find any error regarding that is for some reason there's a flaw in my code where i suppressed the exception error and still displayed a message as if it was working properly.